# Show all form entries of gravity form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using `gravity form`. I want to show all the form entries of specific form on front end for this purpose i use the `plugin` `Gravity Forms Directory` but the issue is that the file path it showing is some thing like [image]
i also use `gravity form` code to get all the entries data which is

```
$form_id = '1';
$entry = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id );
print_r($entry);
```

But the issue is remain same the file path is not showing properly. Any idea how can i get the file path. Thanks

Response from query:
[image]

Comment: What's the response from your print_r?

Comment: @DavidWyly sorry for late reply i added the response in post

Comment: Is the file path information available for `form_id` in the database?

Comment: I would tag this with 'wordpress' as well. You may get more help that way. Also, the data looks like it's serialized. Does unserializing it help?

Comment: i did not try unserializing, let me try it

Comment: i got it, these are the id's of post. Thanks for help